# The requested URL was not found only on localhost

Tags: urls, migration

I have moved WordPress files & database from localhost to live server successfully. However, now when I try to move it back to localhost the links doesn't work, although they should.

I am using root-relative links in my hrefs as in: href="/about-us"

I am using the plugin All in One WP Migration.

Have tried the following:

- Multiple .wpress backup files from the plugin,
- Reinstalled XAMPP,
- Several different database names for local WP installation,
- Severeal different usernames for local WP installation,
- Several different theme names for local WP installation,
- Matched database, username and theme name Exactly as live WP installation,

After WP migration have tried:

- Selecting all the other permalink structures in addition to "postname",
- Saving permalink structure twice after WP Migration,
- Cleared cache with Google Inspector,
- And maybe something more.

All the "guides" seem to use this plugin with "ease" and none really faces this issue or talks about it so it's quite confusing.

Note: If I change from "/about-us" to "about-us" it works but I do not want it this way. Also I want to make this work with this specific plugin.

Thanks!

//Edits below

Seems to be an issue with Apache. When comparing `.htaccess` file content between live and localhost (after migrating site with plugin), this is the result:

**Live** site `.htaccess` content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Local** site .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /viktoria-cafe-konditori/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /viktoria-cafe-konditori/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I see that there are differences on the RewriteBase line and on the last RewriteRule line.

I tried to copy all content from live `.htaccess` to local `.htaccess` - problem persists.

Comment: can you be more specific what you meant by not found? 404 error page? Nginx/Apache error page? Unable to find host? Blank page? _Note that 3rd party plugin support questions are off topic here and not in this stacks scope_, as are hosting issues, you're much more likely to get an answer going to their support or asking other WP Migrate users

Comment: it's also possibly you forgot to turn on pretty permalinks

Comment: It seems to be an Apache error. This is displayed: 

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/8.1.6 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: then that doesn't sound much like a WordPress error, but an Apache one. If it was WP related you'd see a 404 page from your theme or the homepage. Did you forget to copy the `.htaccess` file over? Resaving permalinks usually writes out a fresh one

Comment: Ok. Using this plugin should not need one to copy over any files including .htaccess. This is the live .htaccess configuration:   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: You shouldn't post code in the comments, edit your question instead. If you don't need to copy it but it isn't copying it then you need to contact their support. As I mentioned earlier, you can't ask support questions for WP Migrate Pro here, 3rd party support questions are off topic and not in this stacks scope, if the plugin is misbehaving or not delivering what it promised you have to take it up with them or other users of that plugin

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help and guidance!